# Number dividing the discriminant of a field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Regarding the first page of [these notes](http://math.nju.edu.cn/~guoxj/articles/2009Gauss.pdf), reproduced below:

> [image]

1. (middle of page): Why exactly can we assume that $y$ is totally positive?
2. (bottom of page): How do we get $b|D$?

Answer (score 0):

For (I), notice that $x$ is totally positive by hypotheses, and hence $\frac { y}{\sigma (y)}$ is also totally positive. This means that $\sigma (y)$ and $y$ have the same sign, and so we can assume that $y$ is totally positive.
For(II), we have just arrived at the conclusion that $J^2=(b)$, and hence the ideal $(b)$ ramifies, i.e. $b \mid D$.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Did I miss something? If so, please tell me. Thanks in any case.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the expression "$(b)$ ramifies". I know what it means for $p$ prime that $(p)$ ramifies and that it implies $p \mid D$, but how does it imply the same result for a square free integer $b$?

Comment: @Gils The unique factorisation of ideals holds, and hence, whatever, $(b)$ factorises, since $(b)=J^2$, its prime factors must ramify. Since it is square-free, this means that $b\mid$ discriminant.